# How can I tell what the username is of an authenticated using Forms Authentication with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

After a user is authenticated I store their username in session state but if the session times out, I want to create a new session for the user based on their username they authenticated with original. How can I get from Forms Authentication the currently authenticated user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current authenticated user should be the name in the [`IIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx) assigned to the identity of the [`IPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) on the `User` property of the `HttpContext`

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

In ASP.NET MVC, it is available in a controller via

```
this.User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store the user name in session at all - in your page simply access the [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx?PHPSESSID=tn8k5...) property of HttpContext. To get the actual username you would use `User.Identity.Name`, and as a handy short cut the ASP.NET Page class itself has a user property, so you could do

```
string userName = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

in your code behind.

If you're using ASP.NET MVC there's a User property you can access in a controller

```
string userName = User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: How about from a MVC Controller?